# I'm looking for a shorter syntax to find and delete files in bash

Tags: bash

I often download files that are in folders. I've already figured out how to find everything I don't want and delete it. I've written my script, then an alias, and it all works fine. It's the syntax that I find laborious. Here's my example. I want to keep only images and videos. To do this, I use a single command, but I find it really too wordy.

Here's the line:

```
find . -type f ! -iname '*.mp4' ! -iname '*.avi' ! -iname '*.mkv' ! -iname '*.mov' ! -iname '*.wmv' ! -iname '*.mpg' ! -iname '*.vob' ! -iname '*.m4v' ! -iname '*.flv' ! -iname '*.ts' ! -iname '*.jpg' ! -iname '*.jpeg' ! -iname '*.png' -delete
```

I was looking for something more like that:

```
find . -type f ! -iname '((*.mp4)|(*.avi)|(*.mkv)|(*.mov)|(*.wmv)|(*.mpg)|(*.vob)|(*.flv)|(*.ts)|(*.jpg)|(*.jpeg)|(*.png))' -delete
```

I know there are solutions with extended globbing, for example using this before the command:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

The thing is, despite my research, I'm not sure how to use all these tools to shorten my commands in general and speed up my writing.

Am I on the right track or do I need to think in a different way?

Comment: FYI, you can split a command across lines, either by ending a line with a backslash, or by creating an array of the command + args and then running it. Either of those would make this much less unwieldy IMHO.

Comment: Using an array to build your `find` command dynamically is another popular approach; then you can have `formats=( mp4 avi mkn mov )` or so forth, and just `for fmt in "${formats[@]}"; do find_args+=( '!' -iname "*.$fmt" ); done` to build up a `find_args` array.

Comment: @Charles Duffy in the line `formats=( mp4 avi mkn mov )` 
is this the real way to write it? 
So my own line would be:
`formats=( mp4 avi mov wmv mpg flv avi mkv jpg jpeg png vob m4v ts )` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the exact syntax to define an array named `formats`. You can use `declare -p formats` to print the contents of the array after it's defined.

Comment: Be sure that when expanding an array you use `"${arrayname[@]}"`, not just `$arrayname` or `"$arrayname"`; without the `${array[@]}` syntax you only get the first element, and without the quotes the original item boundaries aren't honored.

Comment: (And if your shell says the syntax is invalid, make sure it's really bash and that you aren't running your script with `sh` or using a `#!/bin/sh` shebang; sh is not bash)

Comment: So in theory, a script like this should work?
`#!/bin/bash

formats=( mp4 avi mov wmv mpg flv avi mkv jpg jpeg png vob m4v ts )

for fmt in "${formats[@]}"; do 
    find_args+=( '!' -iname "*.$fmt" ); 
done`

Comment: I mean, you then need to _use_ the `find_args` array to invoke `find`, and it'd be good form to initialize it before the loop (`find_args=( )`), but I don't expect anything there to fail.

Comment: @Charles Duffy
I created .txt files in a folder and it didn't list them...

Comment: Right, because you aren't doing the "then need to _use_ the `find_args` array" part.

Comment: That would be something like `find . "${find_args[@]}" -type f -print`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255392/discussion-between-martin-julien-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically generate a `find` command line from an array of extensions you want to ignore.

Consider:

```
#!/bin/bash

# First, define which formats you want
formats=( mp4 avi mov wmv mpg flv avi mkv jpg jpeg png vob m4v ts )

# Second, use that formats array to create a find_args array
for fmt in "${formats[@]}"; do
  find_args+=( '!' -iname "*.$fmt" );
done

# Third, expand that find_args array onto your find command line
find . "${find_args[@]}" -type f -print
```

See this working in an online sandbox at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/PapayawhipProfuseMicroinstruction#main.sh

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks for everything!
Martin

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
find . -type f ! -iregex '.*\.\(mp4\|avi\|mkv\|mov\|wmv\|mpg\|vob\|flv\|ts\|jpg\|jpeg\|png\)' -delete
```

You can make the regular expression cleaner (at the expense of adding the `-regextype` option to `find`) with:

```
find . -type f -regextype egrep ! -iregex '.*\.(mp4|avi|mkv|mov|wmv|mpg|vob|flv|ts|jpg|jpeg|png)' -delete
```

Comment: The second one is the clearest of syntaxes. There's just a bug with the -regextype option.

I get this answer from the Shell:
find: -regextype: unknown primary or operator

Sorry to ask so many questions, it's just that I'm a deep learner... I'm no match for any of you ;-) But thank you for helping me and speeding up my learning process ;-)

Comment: @MartinJulien The error suggests you're using BSD find (mac?) - the equivalent option should be `-E` e.g. `find -E . -type f ! -iregex '...'` (you could also install `findutils` via homebrew to get GNU find)

Comment: @pjh
Thanks a lot. I sitched to the GNU find and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` to find all files, but then utilize `grep` to filter out the files you want to keep, and then the result will be all ELSE you would want to remove:

Here's a oneliner: (you can improve and add all the extensions you need)

```bash
find . -type f -print0|grep -Eviz 'mp4$|avi$|mkv$|mov$|jpg$|png$'|while IFS= read -r -d '' file;do rm -f -- "$file";done
```

Comment: Note that this will misbehave if any of the filepaths contain whitespace (which is fairly unusual on Unix-like systems, but is absolutely valid).

Comment: `xargs` will misbehave, but the `while` loop will not

Comment: It's much safer to use NUL-delimited streams than newline-delimited ones to handle list of filenames, _particularly_ if those filenames are outside your control / haven't been manually audited.

Comment: @Ron, the `while` loop _can_ misbehave here. You could make it safer with `find -print0`, `grep -z`, and `while IFS= read -r -d '' file`

Comment: ...the `IFS=` fixes behavior with leading and trailing whitespace on your names, the `-r` fixes misbehavior with names with backslashes in them, the `-d ''` switches to expect newlines to separate names, so names with newlines contained _within_ them won't be split.

Comment: @Ron ...also, `rm -f -- "$file"` to fix support for filenames that start with dashes (though with `find .` they'll all start with `.`s, so you shouldn't hit that here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the tips. Tested and updated my answer

Comment: (oof, I misspoke above, I should have said "switches to expect NULs, instead of newlines, to separate names...")